# Ajgularjs bootstrap calendar rendering partially with error ngModel required

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

Always getting error: Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'datepicker',can't be found!

If I move the same code in another application, it works perfectly, so what I am missing

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text"
            datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
            ng-model="fromdate"
            is-open="open"
            ng-required="true"
            class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open = !open;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

Complete controller to test :

```
app.controller('dateCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.open = false;
    $scope.fromdate = '';
}])
```

Here is the complete error:

Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'datepicker', can't be found!

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=datepicker
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:68:12)
    at getControllers (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:8009:19)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:8156:33)
    at delayedNodeLinkFn (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:8400:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:7543:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:7418:30)
    at $get.boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:7562:16)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost/Tsomeapp/Scripts/angular.js:8179:18)
    at ngDirective.link (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:27880:5)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost/someapp/Scripts/angular.js:8652:9) <li ng-transclude="">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12332$get @ angular.js:9111invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8654nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8152compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7543nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8147compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7543publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7418$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7562controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8179ngIfWatchAction @ angular.js:23814$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15685$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15953(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23305n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
angular.js:12332 

 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at k (ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:8)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:16167)
    at ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:8
    at angular.js:17711
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5396)
    at angular.js:5668
```

It renders only

[image]

Comment: what does the `{{format}}` resolve to? that would be the template that is being used

Comment: $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
That is the date format

Comment: `$scope.fromdate` should be a `Date`, not a `String`; try `$scope.fromdate = new Date();`

Comment: I tried that as well ,even the type ='date' but noting working, same code is working in in other applications, I tried by copying and pasting, it's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to a directive I created earlier to use the jQuery datepicker, just I removed that directive and everything working smooth now,

I am not deleting this question, considering it may help someone, here is the directive

```
app.directive('datepicker', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
                $(el).datepicker({
                    onSelect: function (dateText) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```